# VS2010 - How do I add association columns to workflow definition

Tags: workflow

I see in the SharePoint Designer that you can specify a list of Association Columns that will be automatically added to a list when a workflow is associated with the list (if the columns don't already exist). What I can't figure out is how to add the list of Association Columns to a workflow definition when you design it in Visual Studio.